# wordpress error when trying to login to backend admin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, authentication

[image: Attached File]

Hello, I would like to ask about wordpress issue at the backend admin login. When I'm trying to login my acct. an error occured based on the picture but when I refresh or resubmit my acct has been login.
Does anyone also encountered this scenario of error? What counter measures to fix the use?

Thanks.

Comment: its probably a action attached after signon, but its something you'll need to find. Search using a texteditor for the function mentioned above.